# Why doesn't AutoScrollMinSize take effect until I mouseover?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a panel and I set AutoScrollMinSize.  I also call Invalidate() on the panel in order to force a paint.  The size of the panel is less than the size of the AutoScrollMinSize values, yet the control does not display the scroll bars until I mouse over the panel.

What would cause this behavior, or how can I have the AutoScrollMinSize take effect immediately?

Comment: When are you setting `AutoScrollMinSize`?

Comment: This has to be environmental, Panel just doesn't behave this way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could be because the control isn't redraw right away (which makes sense in this case).

You could instead call `Refresh()` on the control. `Refresh()` forces the control to be invalid *and* send a `WM_PAINT` message *immediately*. `Invalidate()` on the other hand basically says "ok the control is invalid...it will redraw with the next `WM_PAINT`".

**EDIT**: [Here's a link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/subhagpo/whats-the-difference-between-control-invalidate-control-update-and-control-refresh) for more information.